# set jquery loader when timeout (window.setTimeout)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, delay, loader

I now have the following functionality in my jQuery file:

```
var timer;
var delay = 1500; // 1,5 second delay after last input

$("#qr_data").bind("input", function (e) {
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = window.setTimeout(function(){
        // get qr code data
        var qr_data = $('#qr_data').val();

        var data = getVCardData(qr_data);

        $("#helpqrcode").modal("hide");


    }, delay);
});
```

As you can see I have a delay of 1,5 second. Is it possible that I can show an image loader while the 1,5 second? In my HTML I have an image like this:

```
<img id="loading" style="display:none; width:200px;" alt="loader" src="recourses/imgs/loader.gif" />
```

Comment: `.show` the image when user starts input, then `.hide` it in the timeout callback.

Comment: @fuyushimoya What do you mean with .show and .hide?

Comment: They're jquery functions to change the visibility of jquery object. [.show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [.hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed the image to text, for convenience for demo.

```js
var timer;
var delay = 1500; // 1.5 second delay after last input

$("#qr_data").bind("input", function (e) {
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
  
    // When user stop input, show the image here.
    $("#test").show();
  
    
    timer = window.setTimeout(function(){
        // When the time is 1.5 second after last input, hide the image.
        $("#test").hide();
      
        // get qr code data
        var qr_data = $('#qr_data').val();
        console.log(qr_data);
        
        
    }, delay);
});
```

```css
#test {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="qr_data" />
<div id="test">Typing</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to show the loading image and when the `change` event is fired you have to hide it:

```
$("#qr_data")
  .one( 'change', function() {
    $('#loading').hide();
    // do stuff with the value of qr_data
  });
$('#loading').show();
```

So you are shure that the data are really changed